# How to invoke a delegate object

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Hi I'm new to C# and currently working on an app using some 3rd party APIs. I came across two lines of code which appreciate it if you could help. Below is the code similar to the actual sample code I have

```
bank.Account.NewAcc += delegate (Customer customerInfo) {
   Console.WriteLine ("Customer Name : " + customerInfo.Name);
};
```

The `bank.Account.NewAcc` is an event while `Customer` is a class.

Below are the questions:

1. Can we create a delegate of `object` and not `method`?
2. How can I invoke it? I don't have any other information provided by the APIs

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the answers to your questions as per my knowldege:

### 1. Can we create a delegate of object and not method?

No. You can't. Because delegates mean Function Pointer. They can hold the reference of functions only. And the method's signature must match with the signature of the delegate.

### 2. How can I invoke it? I don't have any other information provided from the APIs

The delegate which is associated with an event as an event handler can be invoked in two ways. First, when the event will be raised, second, when you invoke event programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code, an anonymous delegate with a single parameter of type `CustomerInfo` has been bound to an event named `NewAcc`.

Once the `NewAcc` event is fired, the bound delegates would be executed, the code to fire \ raise the event could be like this:

> public Class BankAccount { .....
>
> ```
>     protected virtual void OnNewAcc(CustomerInfo customerInfo)
>     {
>         CustomerEventHandler handler = NewAcc;
>         if (handler != null)
>         {
>             handler(this, customerInfo);
>         }
>     }
>
>     public event CustomerEventHandler NewAcc;
> ```
>
> > .... }

I hope this answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. I am not quite sure what you mean by a delegate of "object". I doubt you can though. Delegates represent a list of methods to be called. You can't just assign any `object` value to it.
2. *You* don't invoke (or *raise*) events. The API does. Judging from the name of `NewAcc`, I guess the event will be raised when a new account is created. Try doing that to `bank.Account`. You might see the customer info getting printed. Obviously, this won't work 100%. You have to look inside `bank.Account` to know exactly when the event will be raised (or just ask the person who wrote it).

Note that the delegate can be written with a lambda expression:

```
bank.Account.NewAcc += (customerInfo) => Console.WriteLine ("Customer Name : " + customerInfo.Name);
```